# de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo fails on GitLab CI

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, gitlab-ci

I have a Spring Boot 2 application running some unit testing using Embendded Mongo (de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo).

The tests when I run locally using
`/gradlew clean build`
It runs normally.

However, when the same application is built on GitLab CI/CD I find the following error:

> WafiraApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
> java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at
> ConstructorResolver.java:800
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at
> ConstructorResolver.java:800
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at
> BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at
> ConstructorResolver.java:800
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at
> ConstructorResolver.java:800
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at
> AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessBuilder.java:1142
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessImpl.java:-2 DepositRepositoryTest > save() FAILED
> java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at
> AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessBuilder.java:1142
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessImpl.java:-2 TransferRepositoryTest > save() FAILED
> java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at
> AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessBuilder.java:1142
> Caused by: java.io.IOException at ProcessImpl.java:-2 ClientRepositoryTest > findByClientEmail() FAILED

This is an example of one test case below:

```
@DataMongoTest
public class DepositRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private DepositRepository depositRepository;

@Test
void save(){
    var deposit = DataGenerator.getDeposityEntityWithFixedValues();

    depositRepository.save(deposit);

    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    depositRepository.findAll().forEach(it -> atomicInteger.addAndGet(1));

    assertThat(atomicInteger.get()).isEqualTo(1);

}
```

Any ideas?